# PHP trim() issue

Tags: php, trim

Lets say I have `$url="../folder/file"` and I want to find and remove the `../` part.

I'm using `trim()` …

```
$url = trim($url,"../");
```

… but it gives me a warning:

> Warning: trim() [function.trim]: Invalid '..'-range, no character to the left of '..'  on line above

What I did wrong?

Comment: If you're only stripping the `../` from the *front* of the string, just use [ltrim()](http://php.net/ltrim).

Answer (score 7):

what you did wrong was fail to read the manual:

> With .. you can specify a range of characters.

```
<?php
$url="../folder/file";
$url = trim($url,"\.\./");
echo $url;
?>
```

Comment: +1: This is the only answer that provides a viable solution: escaping the two dots

Comment: This is not the only viable solution.  This is actually a misleading solution.  You only need to specify the dot in the list of characters to be trimmed once.  The second arguement is not a substring to be trimmed, it is a list of characters that should be trimmed.  If his string was "...../folder/file", specifying a single dot would still work.

Comment: @jmkelm08 actually @shea is right and the misleading answer is yours. The user wants to remove the `../` part; if you only specify one single it will remove it, right... but would also remove a potentially `./` part, which is *not* what the user wants. So escaping the two dots is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ltrim

```
echo ltrim("../folder/file", "./");
```

or

```
echo trim("../folder/file", "./");
```

Comment: I received the same error if the string didn't contain the dots. Escaping the dots worked in the answer above however.

Answer (score 1):

There is a special syntax in the trim function from [php.net/trim](http://php.net/trim) that allows you to specify a range, which is what the interpreter believes you are doing because of the '..'

```
// trim the ASCII control characters at the beginning and end of $binary
// (from 0 to 31 inclusive)
$clean = trim($binary, "\x00..\x1F");
var_dump($clean);
```

The second argument to trim should be a string of characters that would be stripped, so you should not have to put the '.' twice.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to the trim function specifies a list of characters to be stripped, not a multi-character string.  The function interprets '..' as an operator specifying a range of characters (like a..z or 1..5).  You can strip out the '../' in a number of ways, but one easy one is this:

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
array_shift($parts);
$url = implode('/', $parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this function in bottom comments of the trim page on php.net that seem to do what you want

```
function trimString($input, $string){
        $input = trim($input);
        $startPattern = "/^($string)+/i";
        $endPattern = "/($string)+$/i";
        return trim(preg_replace($endPattern, '', preg_replace($startPattern,'',$input)));
}
```